# Access ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager in new Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to access the `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager` in a new controller in ASP.NET MVC 5. I've read through lots of similar posts but cannot see what I'm doing wrong

1.Add new Controller (MVC 5 Controller Empty)

2.Add constructors similar to AccountController and ManagerController to pass `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager`

Example controller looks as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace IR.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AdminController()
        {
        }

        public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync("email@email.com");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

However, only the empty constructor is called and `var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync("email@email.com");` fails as `_userManager == null`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question by now, but for those coming here with the same question, here's an answer.

The code for the managers above is the MVC 5 template's standard implementation code for a project set with individual user accounts. Both managers are implemented in the same way, so we will keep focus on the `ApplicationUserManager` in question here, but it applies to the `ApplicationSignInManager` as well.

The `ApplicationUserManager` is implemented as a public property with a private backing field - `private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;`
The backing field is used for holding the state of the property and as such is not meant for being used directly in the calling code. That's what the public property `UserManager` is for.
So how does this property gets set to return an instance of the `ApplicationUserManager` class instead of null?

There are 2 solutions for that. One is by instantiating the `AdminController` class through it's overloaded constructor:

```
public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

But I will argue that it's only in some edge cases that you would do that. In most cases the controller classes are instantiated by the http request. You can actually delete this constructor, because the solution is already implemented in the property's getter:

```
return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

When the application is started, the Startup class calls the `ConfigureAuth()` method that instantiates the managers:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
        }
```

This line stores the `ApplicationUserManager` in the OwinContext.

```
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

SO - when the controller is instantiated through the request, the backing field is not being set. But when using the property, the getter checks for null value (??) and if null, returns the `ApplicationUserManager` from the OwinContext:

```
return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

So the answer to the above question is, use UserManager - not _userManager.

```
var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("email@email.com");
```